# Sybase ASE new id function behavior

Tags: sap-ase, newid

We use the Sybase function Newid() to generate UUID, that works fine and the generate UUID are unique, however, we noticed after hundred executions that the last 12 chars of the generated UUID are the same. is it a normal behavior of this function in Sybase or there is a specific config that implies this ?
thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The last 12 characters are the ["node"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format). This value depends on the [version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Versions) of UUID begin generated. I don't know which version Sybase ASE or Sybase ASIQ uses.

- [Sybase ASE Documentation for newid()](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1600/doc/html/san1393050471163.html)
- [Sybase ASIQ Documentation for newid()](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1604/doc/html/san1278453091851.html)

Comment: thanks for the response, we use ASE 16, As I understand the 12 characters will never change, that limits the number of combinations!